# How do I force PyCharm to warn about undeclared types?

Tags: python, types, pycharm, type-hinting, typechecking

I want PyCharm to warn me when I forgot to declare types for a function or a variable. Is there any way to make PyCharm do that?

Comment: declaring type for python variable?! is this what you mean? https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: No, I meant [actual variable types when I declare them](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), like `numbers: List[int] = [1,2,3]`. I hear this is new on Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

[On official blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/09/pycharm-2016-3-eap-is-available-with-initial-support-for-python-3-6/) there are some words about PEP 526 support

> Syntax for variable annotations PyCharm 2016.3
>   EAP brings support for the new PEP 526 Python 3.6 standard, which
>   introduces the syntax for type annotations of variables including
>   class variables and instance variables. That means PyCharm now
>   recognizes the new syntax and uses this meta information about types
>   for type inference. Ultimately this positively affects code
>   completion, inspections and error checking

I really doubt it's possible to make PyCharm forcing declaring types. It's not a statically typed language and declaring types should be optional.

Comment: Agree that is MUST be optional. But the key word is "optional", so someone who wants to enforce it should be able to activate the option.